# Why can SN2 reactions occur when the reagents are a primary substrate and a weak nucleophile/base?

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, elimination

The reagents are ethyl bromide and water. In this [Khan Academy video at 5:20](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/organic-chemistry/substitution-elimination-reactions/substitution-elimination-reactions/sn1-sn2-e1-e2-jay/v/elimination-vs-substitution-primary-substrate?modal=1), the narrator says because ethyl bromide is a primary substrate, the reaction is neither S<sub>N</sub>1 or E1. This makes sense because S<sub>N</sub>1 and E1 favor tertiary carbocation.

But between S<sub>N</sub>2 and E2 reaction, the narrator says S<sub>N</sub>2 is more favorable. However, water is a weak nucleophile/base, while S<sub>N</sub>2 or E2 reactions require a strong nucleophile/base.

Why are S<sub>N</sub>2/E2 able to happen in this case? Is it because water can only act as a weak base but not a weak nucleophile so that S<sub>N</sub>2 is more favorable?